# How to conditionally disable client side validation in xVal?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, xval

I am using xVal in a ASP.NET MVC project. One of the forms has two buttons and i want to disable the client side validation when one of the buttons is clicked.  Is there a way to conditionally disable client side validation in xVal?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling client side validation... we can have rules execution only when we need it with the help of JQuery validate method.

For Example:
On button click event upon which validation rules to be fired... apply jquery form validation...

```
$("#ButtonID").click(function() {
    var valid = $("#FormID");   // Form ID to be entered
    //var validDate = validateDate(f);
    var validForm = valid.validate().form();
    // Set delay for 500ms so that all ajax validations would complete.
    setTimeout(function() { $("#FormID").validate().form(); }, 500);    // Form ID to be entered
    validForm = valid.validate().form();

    if (validForm) {
        // Post form data to server
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about xVal in particular, but with an Asp.Net form you can do the following-

```
<asp:Button id="IgnoreClientValidation" runat="server" Text="Ignore Client" EnableClientScript="False" />
```